# Connection lost between C++ and Matlab Engine

Tags: c++, matlab-engine

I have a mission to call Matlab functions from C++ poject. I know there are several ways to do that, I prefer to use it through Matlab Engine.

1. I have several m-files work perfect in Matlab enviroment.

   mymat.m

   ```
   function myfig()
       figure;
   end
   ```
2. I made a dll-wrapper in C++ to connect the m-files with C++.

   dllwrap.h

   ```
   #pragma once

   #include <Engine.h>

   #pragma comment  ( lib,"libmx.lib" )
   #pragma comment  ( lib,"libmat.lib" )
   #pragma comment  ( lib,"libeng.lib" )
   #pragma comment  ( lib,"libmex.lib" )

   #ifdef DLLWRAP_EXPORTS
   #define DLLWRAP_API __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define DLLWRAP_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif

   DLLWRAP_API bool TestDll();
   DLLWRAP_API void MyFigure();
   ```

   dllwrap.cpp

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "dllwrap.h"

   Engine* pEng = NULL;

   void StartVirtualEngineMatlab()
   {
       if ((pEng = engOpen(NULL)) == NULL)
       {
           MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPSTR)"Can't start MATLAB engine!", (LPSTR) "MatLab Engine: ERROR!", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
           return;
       };
       return;
   }

   void StopedVirtualEngineMatlab()
   {
       engClose(pEng);
       return;
   }

   DLLWRAP_API bool TestDll()
   {
       if (pEng == NULL) return false;
       return true;
   }

   DLLWRAP_API void MyFigure()
   {
       engEvalString(pEng, "myfig();");
   }
   ```

   dllmain.cpp

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "dllwrap.h"

   extern Engine* pEng;

   extern void StartVirtualEngineMatlab();
   extern void StopedVirtualEngineMatlab();

   BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                          DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                          LPVOID lpReserved
                    )
   {
       switch (ul_reason_for_call)
       {
       case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
           StartVirtualEngineMatlab();
           break;
       case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
       case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
       case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
           StopedVirtualEngineMatlab();
           break;
       }
       return TRUE;
   }
   ```
3. Now I am in focus on a Test project (C# Console Application) to call a m-files through dll-wraper.

   Test.cs

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   namespace Test
   {
       class Program
       {
           [DllImport("dllwrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
           public static extern bool TestDll();
           [DllImport("dllwrap.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
           public static extern void MyFigure();

                   static void Main(string[] args)
                   {
                       bool res = TestDll();
                       if (res == false)
                           return;

                       MyFigure();
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

The Test project is running and doing the job, but there is a problem. A Matlab Engine crashes in unexpected time. It may crash at the begining or after a while. I even tried to stop on breaking point right after the engOpen(NULL) function, but the crashing is seems not depending on my break.

I use Visual Studio 2013, Matlab 2015a 32bit.
Please help in advise. 
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so you have a bug in your code. There's nothing we can do to help you without a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), beyond suggesting you fire up your debugger and step through the program  methodically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.
I just removed the line:

```
StopedVirtualEngineMatlab();
```

from dllmain.cpp

```
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    StopedVirtualEngineMatlab();
    break;
}
```

and put it as external funtion to call it from the end of the code of Test.cs.

Now it works perfect.

But still I don't understand why the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH case is invoked...?